# Regex to validate user names with at least one letter and no special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm trying to write a user name validation that has the following restrictions:

1. Must contain at least 1 letter (a-zA-Z)
2. May not contain anything other than digits, letters, or underscores

The following examples are valid: abc123, my_name, 12345a

The following examples are invalid: 123456, my_name!, _1235

I found something about using positive lookaheads for the letter contraint: (?=.*[a-zA-Z]), and it looks like there could be some sort of negative lookahead for the second constraint, but I'm not sure how to mix them together into one regex. (Note... I am not really clear on what the .* portion does inside the lookahead...)

Is it something like this: /(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*[^a-zA-Z0-9_])/

**Edit:**

Because the question asks for a regex, the answer I'm accepting is:

```
 /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/
```

However, the thing I'm actually going to implement is the suggestion by Bryan Oakley to split it into multiple smaller checks.  This makes it easier to both read and extend in the future in case requirements change. Thanks all!

And because I tagged this with ruby-on-rails, I'll include the code I'm actually using:

```
validate :username_format    

def username_format
  has_one_letter = username =~ /[a-zA-Z]/
  all_valid_characters = username =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
  errors.add(:username, "must have at least one letter and contain only letters, digits, or underscores") unless (has_one_letter and all_valid_characters)
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/`: 0 or more valid characters followed by one alphabetical followed by 0 or more valid characters, constrained to be both the beginning and the end of the line.

Comment: Sweet, it's missing a _ in the first test for 0 or more valid, but apart from that, it works!

Answer (score 6):

It's easy to check whether the pattern has any illegal characters, and it's easy to check whether there's at least one letter. Trying to do that all in one regular expression will make your code hard to understand.

My recommendation is to do two tests. Put the tests in functions to make your code absolutely dead-simple to understand:

```
if no_illegal_characters(string) && contains_one_alpha(string) {
    ...
}
```

For the former you can use the pattern `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`, and for the latter you can use `[a-zA-Z]`.

If you don't like the extra functions that's ok, just don't try to solve the problem with one difficult-to-read regular expression. There are no bonus points awarded for cramming as much functionality into one expression as possible.

Comment: There's a small bug in your "no_illegal_characters()" regex, Bryan. As it is now the regex is saying "the string must be only 1 character long from start to finish". Instead of `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]$` it should be `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`.

Comment: Thanks @wyatt, I changed the expression to include the `+`

Answer (score 2):

the simplest regex that resolve your problem is:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/
```

I encourage you to try it out live on http://rubular.com/

Comment: That's not a perfect solution: it won't allow 12345a.

Comment: Looks like this is very close, but also imposed the restriction that it must start with a letter, so 12345a does not pass.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought that 12345a is invalid: the correct one is /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/

Comment: @Ireneusz Skrobis: no, that won't work either because that will match a string with only a number (ie: it will match "42")

Comment: what a bummer :P but it seems that Shea Levy post the correct answer, isn't he?